# strdup() memory leak even after free()

Tags: c, gcc, memory-leaks, posix

I've never needed to use `strdup(stringp)` with `strsep(&stringp_copy, token)` together until recently and I think it was causing a memory leak.

(`strdup()` has always `free`'d just fine before.)

I fixed the leak, and I think I understand how, but I just can't figure out why I needed to.

Original code (summarized):

```
const char *message = "From: username\nMessage: basic message\n";
char *message_copy, *line, *field_name;
int colon_position;
message_copy = strdup(message);

while(line = strsep(&message_copy, "\n")) {
  printf(line);
  char *colon = strchr(line, ':');
  if (colon != NULL) {
    colon_position = colon - line;
    strncpy(field_name, line, colon_position);
    printf("%s\n", field_name);
  }
}

free(message_copy);
```

New code that doesn't leak:

```
const char *message = "From: username\nMessage: basic message\n";
char *message_copy, *freeable_message_copy, *line, *field_name;
int colon_position;
freeable_message_copy = message_copy = strdup(message);

while(line = strsep(&message_copy, "\n")) {
  printf(line);
  char *colon = strchr(line, ':');
  if (colon != NULL) {
    colon_position = colon - line;
    strncpy(field_name, line, colon_position);
    printf("%s\n", field_name);
  }
}

free(freeable_message_copy);
```

How is the `message_copy` pointer being overwritten in the first code? or is it?

Comment: Comment: don't do `printf(line)`; if `line` contains what looks like `printf()` format string conversion specs, it will end up reading, or writing, the wrong memory.  Use either `fputs(line, stdout)` or `printf("%s", line)` — either is safe and they are equivalent.

Comment: `message_copy` is overwritten by strsep. Read the man.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler. `printf(line)` was for quick and dirty debugging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function strsep() takes a pointer to the original string (message_copy) and modifies it to return a new pointer to the 'next' token

```
const char *message = "From: username\nMessage: basic message\n";
char *message_copy, *original_copy;
//here you have allocated new memory, a duplicate of message
message_copy = original_copy = strdup(message);
```

Print out the pointer here,

```
printf("copy %p, original %p\n", message_copy, original_copy);
```

Note that as you use strsep(), you are modifying the message_copy,

```
char* token;
//here you modify message_copy
while(token = strsep(&message_copy, "\n")) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
}
```

This illustrates the changed message_copy, while original_copy is unchanged,

```
printf("copy %p, original %p\n", message_copy, original_copy);
```

Since message_copy does not point to the original strdup() result this would be wrong,

```
free(message_copy);
```

But keep around the original strdup() result, and this free works

```
//original_copy points to the results of strdup
free(original_copy);
```

Comment: I completely missed that it modified the pointer in the `strsep` man page.

Answer (score 6):

Because `strsep()` modifies the `message_copy` argument, you were trying to free a pointer that was not returned by `malloc()` et al.  This would generate complaints from some `malloc()` libraries, and from [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).  It is also undefined behaviour, usually leading to crashes in short order (but crashes in code at an inconvenient location unrelated to the code that did the damage).

In fact, your loop iterates until `message_copy` is set to NULL, so you were freeing NULL, which is defined and safe behaviour, but it is also a no-op.  It did not free the pointer allocated via `strdup()`.

Summary:

- Only free pointers returned by the memory allocators.
- Do not free pointers into the middle or end of a block returned by the memory allocators.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the `strsep` man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html).

In short the `strsep` function will modify the original character pointer that's passed into the function, overwriting each occurrance of the delimiter with a `\0`, and the original character pointer is then updated to point past the `\0`.

Your second version doesn't leak, as you created a temporary pointer to point to the start of the original char pointer returned from `strdup()`, so the memory was freed correctly, as you called `free()` with the original char pointer instead of the updated one that `strsep()` had modified.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page,

...This token is terminated by overwriting the delimiter with a null byte ('\0') and `*stringp is updated to point past the token`....