# Undetected leak with asan and strsep()

Tags: c, gcc, address-sanitizer

GCC 8.2.0 does not detect the leak in the following code compiled with `-fsanitize=address`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *str1 = "tok1:val2";
        char *str1_dup = strndup(str1, strlen(str1));
        char *str1_dup_head = str1_dup;

        char *tok1 = strsep(&str1_dup, ":");

        // What should be done to avoid the memory leak
        //free(str1_dup_head);
        return 0;
}
```

However, the leak is detected when:

- compiled with `-fsanitize=leak`
- compiled with `clang -fsanitize=address`
- when a copy on the head of the pointer given to `strsep()` (`str1_dup_cpy`) is not kept (see code below)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *str1 = "tok1:val2";
        char *str1_dup = strndup(str1, strlen(str1));
        //char *str1_dup_head = str1_dup;

        char *tok1 = strsep(&str1_dup, ":");

        // What should be done to avoid the memory leak
        //free(str1_dup_head);
        return 0;
}
```

Any idea why is this behaviour ? Should it be detected by `-fsanitize=address`?

Comment: `strndup` allocates storage for the copied characters.

Comment: @Barmar no because strsep() moves the pointer. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000218/strdup-memory-leak-even-after-free. And man strsep.

Comment: @JeffBencteux Thanks, didn't see that the variable was being used there.

Comment: Way late here, but `char *str1_dup = strndup(str1, strlen(str1));` is just `strdup()`.  There's absolutely no point in using `strndup()` when you have to use `strlen()` to get the length of the string anyway.

Answer (score 1):

LeakSanitizer by design uses a simple algorithm for leak detection. Whenever a reference to allocated block happens to be somewhere on stack, register or live heap block, LSan considers it to be "reachable" and thus does not report a leak. This makes it very sensitive to compiler versions, optimization options (i.e. whether variable is spilled to stack or not), etc. I strongly suspect you are experiencing this limitation.

Comment: Do you know why using LeakSanitizer with `-fsanitize=leak` gives different results from implicitely enabling it with `-fsanitize=address` ?

Comment: @JeffBencteux Just to double check, does `export ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1` change anything?

Comment: No, same results with the above environment variable.